# Properly expose function in webpack build so HTML can access it

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I just was introduced to webpack and not sure how to do something very basic.

This is my webpack file.

```
 const webpack = require('webpack');
    module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    entry: "./src/game.ts",
    output: {
        path: __dirname, 
        filename: "myGame.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { 
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: ['awesome-typescript-loader?tsconfig=tsconfig.json']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my markup file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tic tac toe</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles.css">
        <script src="game.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="center">
            <button type="button" onclick="resetGame()">
                New game
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <div class="cell" onclick="cellClicked(event, 0, 0)"></div>
                <div class="cell" onclick="cellClicked(event, 1, 0)"></div>
                <div class="cell" onclick="cellClicked(event, 2, 0)"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
</html>
```

How will my mark up know what cellClicked and reset functions are?

I know I can set them to window object and then it will know but it feels like a bad design.

Can anyone help me understand webpack since it feels I have no handle on it.

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Can you link to a project or example where you saw this functionality being used?

Comment: this is something i am working locally. It tictactoe game, where i keep gameboard logic in ts, but cellClicked function is not found and its right there in ts file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is one way to do it.

```
{
  "output": {
    "library": your_obj,
    "libraryTarget": "var"
  }
}
```

Comment: but its not a library, is it?